# How do we calculate total data scanned by Athena WorkGroup per day

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena

I have a requirment were i need to caliculate the total data scanned in the workgrop (MytestWG).

Using CW alarm i could see "ProcessedBytes" which helps us to find the number of bytes that Athena scanned per DML query.

I need to set alarm on WG level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_QueryExecutionStatistics.html), there is `dataScannedInBytes` data. So you can run this on Logs Insights to calculate data by specific workgroup.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter type = 'QueryStateChangeEvent' and state = 'SUCCEEDED' and workgroup = 'MytestWG'
| filter contains(queryExecutionContext.sql, 'SELECT')
| stats sum(queryExecutionContext.statistics.dataScannedInBytes) as dataScannedInBytes by bin(1d)
```

to create an alarm from that data:

1. Go to Open the AWS CloudWatch console and navigate to the "Alarm"
2. Click "Create Alarm" button
3. Select the Athena namespace metric then choose the "WorkGroups" dimension.
4. Select the "DataScannedInBytes" metric.
5. Change period select option to 1 day. (24 hours)
6. Configure to the threshold value as you like, sum/average, greater than or something like that.
7. Click next and then set the alarm notification trigger setting, (eg send to email notification)
8. Click next to set alarm name and description
9. Click next and then review the alarm detail
10. Click Create Alarm Button

Comment: anything like Cloudwatch alarm we can create on WG level.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad, i also got this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/workgroups-setting-control-limits-cloudwatch.html#configure-control-limit-per-workgroup

Comment: which log group do we need to select while running the above query in log insights... were does workgroup stores the total data scanned @Muhammad Dyas